# Pinia Stores not running as expected on my desktop but run fine on my laptop

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, pinia

I work with a team that use Pinia for state management across a Vue ( & vuetify ) application, everything works fine on their machines and on my laptop. However, when I am using my desktop pinia doesn't seem to work and I am certain that I've set up the application the same way on both devices,I've even re-setup the env on my desktop multiple times.

When I load an application on my laptop I see  `"currentUser" store installed`  and I am able to access it as expected with no issues, the Pinia tab appears in my Vue devtools too.

When I load the application on my desktop I do not see a 'store installed' prompt and everything is passed as a ref `__v_isRef: true` but the Pinia tab still appears in my Vue devtools...

If I `console.log()` a value in the store I get the response I'd expect but, when I `console.log()` a variable in the store on my desktop I get the following:

```js
{
  value: false,
  __V_isRef: true,
  get value: function value(){},
  set value: function value(){},
}
```

Now for another spanner, the code below works perfectly fine if I run it in something like codepen leading me to think its something with node / vue / vuetify, how could I check if it is?

```js
    const useCounterStore = Pinia.defineStore('counter', {
      state() {
        return {
          value: 0
        }
      },
      actions: {
        increment(state) {
          this.value++
        },
      }
    })

    Vue.use(Pinia.PiniaVuePlugin)
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        pinia: Pinia.createPinia(),
        computed: {
          ...Pinia.mapState(useCounterStore, ['value'])
        },
        methods: {
          ...Pinia.mapActions(useCounterStore, ['increment', 'incrementBugged'])
        },
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <v-app>
        <v-main>
            <v-container>Count is: {{ value }}</v-container>
            <button @click="increment">Click here, works on both my desktop and laptop</button>
        </v-main>
    </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@vue/composition-api"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please LMK if you need any additional information :)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Please do not add a link to your code. See [mcve] and [edit] the question to contain all relevant code within the question itself. Links can rot, people might not be able to access the website, there might be licensing issues etc.

Comment: what versions are you using? for pinia, vue, vuetify, devtools, etc

Comment: @BernardoDalCorno , Thanks for the response and sorry for the late reply
vue: ^2.6.12,
pinia: ^2.0.20,
vuetify: ^2.6.9,

I think my devtools are running at Version 2.7.8

Comment: The message "store installed" is a [setting in devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/1723), that could lead some of the differences. Also, check global packages in desktop vs laptop via `npm ls -g --depth 0`

Comment: So I've got a few extra packages installed on my laptop compared to my Desktop but they are for ionic, on my laptop I'm running @angular/cli@12.0.4, bower@1.8.12, cordova-res@0.15.3, cordova@10.0.0, ionic@5.4.16, native-run@1.3.0, npm@7.17.0, properties-parser@0.3.1, vue-cli@2.9.6. for my desktop I'm running @ionic/cli@6.19.0, @nestjs/cli@7.6.0, @vue/cli-init@5.0.8, @vue/cli@5.0.8, yarn@1.22.18.  [here's a link to an imgur for better formatting](https://imgur.com/a/C7BOx71). so my assumption is that I should get vue-cli on my desktop to have parity with my laptop and that should solve the bug